# calling an API inside a functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want a call an API depending on the value selected from the dropdown in my functional component. I have defined a function outside my function component that accepts argument and call an API. I am using useState hook to store the value selected in action_name state value. But that state is not available in callSomeAPI function. Should I move callSomeAPIfunction inside my component? Is it even a efficient approach?

```
    function callSomeAPI(container_name) {
      console.log(container_name);
      action_name = event.target.value;
      let e = document.getElementById("actions")
      console.log(e.target)
      action_name = e.target
      fetch(<some_url>, {
        method: 'PUT',
      })
        .then(response => console.log(response.json()))
        .catch(console.log("error problem in api request"));
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    export function AlertsRenderer(props) {
      const [action_name, callSomeAPI] = useState(null);
      return (
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th> Column1 </th>
            <th> Column2 </th>
            <th> Column3 </th>
            <th> Button </th>
            <th> Actions </th>
          </tr>
          {props.alerts.map(alert => (
            <tr key={alert.id.toString()}>
              <td>{alert.data1}</td>
              <td>{alert.data2}</td>
              <td>{alert.data3}</td>
              <td>
                <button value={alert.id} onClick={() => markAsSolved(alert.id)}>Mark as solved</button>
              </td>
              <td>
                <select  defaultValue={action_name} onChange={() => callSomeAPI(alert.data1)} name="actions" id="actions">
                  <option hidden disabled selected value>Select an action</option>
                  <option value="inc-disk">Increase disk size</option>
                  <option value="restart-php">Restart PHP</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
              ))}
        </table>
      );
    }
```

Comment: What you are doing here is bizarre.  You need a callSomeAPI function that takes the selected value as an argument.  Don’t get it from the DOM.  Use a controlled select.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook to listen when action_name is changed and fetch api when action_change

```
function fetchAPI(action_name) {
      fetch(<some_url>, {
        method: 'PUT',
      })
        .then(response => console.log(response.json()))
        .catch(console.log("error problem in api request"));
      e.preventDefault();
    }


 export function AlertsRenderer(props) {
      const [action_name, callSomeAPI] = useState(null);
     
      useEffect(()=> {
         fetchAPI(action_name)
     }, [action_name]) 

      return (
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th> Column1 </th>
            <th> Column2 </th>
            <th> Column3 </th>
            <th> Button </th>
            <th> Actions </th>
          </tr>
          {props.alerts.map(alert => (
            <tr key={alert.id.toString()}>
              <td>{alert.data1}</td>
              <td>{alert.data2}</td>
              <td>{alert.data3}</td>
              <td>
                <button value={alert.id} onClick={() => markAsSolved(alert.id)}>Mark as solved</button>
              </td>
              <td>
                <select  defaultValue={action_name} onChange={() => callSomeAPI(alert.data1)} name="actions" id="actions">
                  <option hidden disabled selected value>Select an action</option>
                  <option value="inc-disk">Increase disk size</option>
                  <option value="restart-php">Restart PHP</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
              ))}
        </table>
      );
    }
```